# Adjust a bond for PIK option

Tags: fixed-income

Is there any literature that discusses adjusting a bond for various PIK (Pay-in-Kind) options? I'm trying to benchmark a loan with a PIK option with non-PIK bonds.

Edit: The loan has a payment in kind option where the borrower can pay interest in a deferred manner.

Comment: Currently your question seems too broad to me, can you specify what the acronym "PIK" stands for and be more precise about the optionality you are speaking about?

Comment: Duplicate of https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/36109/is-there-a-way-to-adjust-a-bond-for-a-pik-option , which unfortunately was never answered

Comment: It depends of what is the payment ? If it is additional bonds i/o cash then you can consider that those coupons are actually callable bonds (the issuer can call them on the coupon date by paying you cash coupon i/o bond coupon).